# Copy FLAC tags to MP3 files?

Tags: mp3, flac, id3, vorbis

I have a number of FLAC files that I'm converting into MP3 files with the following:

```
flac -cd file.flac | lame ... - file.mp3
```

Is there a utility which will copy Vorbis (FLAC and OGG) metadata, convert it to appropriate ID3 tags, and tag an MP3 with the same tags as the FLAC file?

Comment: You can use `avconv` for the conversion and have it [copy the metadata](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/176945/17409). ("Trivial answer converted to comment" -- why, thank you SE!)

Comment: I'm trying to piece something together with `mutagen` to translate and copy the tags. I'm a purist and like to deal with the actual `flac` and `lame` binaries ;)

Comment: Happy tinkering then; from my reading, there's no clean method but "read all tags with tool A and write them with tool B" since the tag formats are incompatible. See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10186/17409), for instance. (Note that `avconv` uses `flac` and `lame` internally.)

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg can do this

```
ffmpeg -i infile.flac -c copy outfile.mp3
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/e1a5402/ff-remux.sh#L55)

Answer (score 1):

[Quod Libet](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/) comes with a command line tool called [operon](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/commands/operon.html) that does this and more:

```bash
operon copy song.flac song.mp3
```

Since Quod Libet is built on Mutagen, it knows about a bunch of obscure tags and how to translate them among the various tagging formats, which is important for some workflows. The only quirk I noticed is that it doesn't copy tags with empty values, but that doesn't bother me.

Comment: ffmpeg overwrites "Encoding settings", while operon preserves them. That's exactly what I needed. Thank you!